# Use string variable value to define dataframe python- Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have generated lots of string variables as follow

```
for i in range(10):
    r='df'+str(i)
    r== pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5),
                   index=["A", "B", "C", "D"],
                   columns=["I", "J", "K", "L", "M"])
```

The result I got is

```
TypeError: Could not compare ['df0'] with block values
```

I am expecting to get

```
df0, df1, ... df9
```

with same index and columns but different values.

Answer (score 0):

I just discover it, it seems that one needs to differentiate between 2 quotation: 1) ' and 2) "

It is important to use the `exec()` function in this case

```
k=[]
for i in range(10):
    r='df'+str(i)
    exec(r + " = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],columns=['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'])")
    k.append(r)
```

To observe the outcome

```
for i in k:
    print(i)
    print(globals()[i])
```